# What is the meaning of # in URL and how can I use that?

Tags: url

I often found some URL which looks like the following:

```
www.something.com/some_page/#someword
```

After writing this page some_page will be open and then scroll will be set so that I can see that "**someword**" at beginning of my screen.

I don't know what the meaning of "#" is. As soon as I make **#someotherword** with any URL it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't.

I am not getting what # is in the URL. Is it any functionality of any language or URL or something else?

It might be possible that you consider my question *newbish*, but I am not into web-designing technologies, I am simply curious about it.

I am not the owner of some website, but when I am concerned with some particular portion of some web page then how can I give the URL with # and give that URL to another?

I am concerned with the answer portion on my profile, and then I will prepare the URL just below and will give it to somebody.

*https://stackoverflow.com/users/775964/mr-32#answers*

This works, but some time it doesn't.

*https://stackoverflow.com/users/775964/mr-32#tags*

That doesn't work.

I am just a user and I don't want to know in which language the website is build.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does #/ means in url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909084/what-does-means-in-url)

Comment: apart from anchors it can also be used in Text Fragments this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72400036/12594882)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Originally it was used as an anchor to jump to an element with the same name/id.

However, nowadays it's usually used with AJAX-based pages since changing the hash can be detected using JavaScript and allows you to use the back/forward button without actually triggering a full page reload.

Comment: If you only use PHP without any JavaScript you can only use it in the classic way of jumping to anchors. The hash is never sent to the server.

Comment: see i am not the owner of some website but when i am concern with  some particular portion of some web-page then how can i give the url with # and give that url to another ?

Comment: You need to check the HTML sourcecode for `<a name="something">` or any element with `id="something"`. You can then simply add `#something` to the URL.

Answer (score 28):

This is known as the "fragment identifier" and is typically used to identify a portion of an HTML document that sits within a fully qualified URL:

[Fragment Identifier Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)

Answer (score 8):

It is an anchor for links within a page - also known as "anchor tag"

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: Only the owner can embed such anchors.

Comment: Oh look - that link has a `#` in it :)

Answer (score 3):

It specifies an "Anchor", or a position on the page, and allows you to "jump" or "scroll" to that position on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from specifying an anchor in a page where you want to jump to, # is also used in jQuery hash or fragment navigation.

- [Anchor with an id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)
- Dead link <strike>[Hash or fragment navigation](http://www.novatek.com.au/news/fragment-navigation)</strike>
- [Tips for better fragment navigation](http://labs.ft.com/2011/02/tips-for-better-fragment-navigation/)

Comment: Thanks for the note. I've added another link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is mainly to anchor your keywords, in particular the location of your page, so whenever URL loads the page with particular anchor name, then it will be pointed to that particular location.

For example, www.something.com/some_page/#computer
if it is very lengthy page and you want to show exactly computer then you can anchor.

```
<p> adfadsf </p>
<p> adfadsf </p>
<p> adfadsf </p>
<a name="computer"></a><p> Computer topics </p>
<p> adfadsf </p>
```

Now the page will scroll and bring computer-related topics to the top.

Comment: It needs to be `"id=computer"`. See [HTML 4 Specification #12.2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3)

Comment: Thanks, name mainly to suite anchor, if you want to support more than that then id is preferable.