# CI Routing for "#" and "?"

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter, routes

I am working on Codeingiter and  have a Function in one of my class.

```
class Search extends My_Controller{

  public function index(){
    //my search code here...
  }

}
```

Now for this function i need set a route so i can make the URL look like

```
 http://example.com/s/?q=searchtext
```

or

```
 http://example.com/s/#q=searchtext
```

However when i do this :

```
$route['s/?q=(:any)'] = "search/index";
$route['s/#q=(:any)'] = "search/index";
```

It does not work and i am being redirected to 404 page.

It seems CI does not allow this kind of Routing. Please tell me how i can do this.

Also If i use   `http://example.com/s/#q=searchtext`

how can i get the value searchtext in my function ?

Comment: The hash is never sent to the server.You can get idea from this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192742/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-url-and-how-can-i-use-that