# Create Links in grails

Tags: grails, gsp

How to create the following link in grails using createlink. I have a list of various parameter, at each iteration, it should generate the link as:

http://localhost:8080/search#parameter="123"

Answer (score 3):

You should use createlink, look in **grails docs** [here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html)

In your case -

```
<g:createLink controller="search" action="index"
              params="[paramater: '123']"/>
```

**or** in you can do like this -

```
<a href="${g.createLink(controller : 'search', action : 'index',params : [paramater : '123',secondParamater: '5'])}"></a>
```

**Important.** This will return params separated with '?' not '#' (Read more about using '#' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192742/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-url-and-how-can-i-use-that))

http://localhost:8080/search?parameter=123&secondParamater=5

But if you really want to use hash parmater(#) -

```
<a href="${g.creteLink(..)}#paramter=123"> </a>
```

*(Can't be sure with your controller/action mapping)