# What does ":" in URL mean?

Tags: ajax, url

some requirement in my school project asks to send some AJAX request to the server to the url :

```
http://localhost:8000/messages/:id
```

where I should set the value of the id as a unique number. I know that `?` means a query search and `#` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909084/what-does-means-in-url)  but what does `:` mean?
and if I set id value to be equal to 123,how it is shown ,like this : `http://localhost:8000/messages/:123`
or like this:`http://localhost:8000/messages/123`

I appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third `:` in the URL you presented is just a placeholder indicating that `id` is a *variable name*.
Therefore, `:id` must be replaced by a *value*, for example 123.

Your second attempt answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ':' in your url. The first one separates the host from the port e.g. `host:port` - in your case the host is localhost, the port is 8000.

Second case, ':id', specifies that the id is a variable. It can be replaced by any value such as '123'. The notation is there so you can differentiate a string in the url (`../messages/id`) from the usage of variables (`../messages/:id`).

All in all you have to drop the `:` in usage as you insert a value for the variable.