# codeigniter making duplicating pages with #! include in link of each page

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I have an issue on my website which is on CodeIgniter.

All links are making a duplicate copy of each with `#!` included in URL 
for example 
https://www.example.com/port-of-portsmouth
 link to a page on my website which is duplicated like the below link

https://www.example.com/port-of-portsmouth#!

Both links have the same page content. How to get rid of this error to avoid content duplication

Comment: Are you using vuejs, angular etc?

Comment: simple CodeIgniter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38909290/2520628

Answer (score 0):

```
How to get rid of this error to avoid content duplication
```

You can't

Because `#` is used as a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). For an example, if the URL is https://example.com/#data this means that open the example.com and jump to a specific section of the page with id"data"

See this URL, https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html#cache
When you open the page, it jumps to `cache` section.

So, basically, your content is not duplicated, it's just opening the same page and then browser tries to navigate to id `!`, which might not be there and hence nothing special happens.

Comment: ok but some SEO tools like ahrefs behave like that with #! and without #! both are different pages,

Comment: Can you show me, how the pages are different? It should be the same page