# What does # mean in https://developer.android.com/

Tags: android, syntax, hyperlink, documentation

I often find links with # such as

> A camera capture session that was switched to offline mode via successful call to CameraCaptureSession#switchToOffline.

for example in https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary

I tried to find everywhere but couldn't find what it means.
I want to know what does `#` mean, why don't they use `.`

Comment: `#` indicates methods `switchToOffline` is a method of `CameraCaptureSession` . `.` is association operator on other hand . you are not calling the method in documentation that's why its not there.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38909290/1133011) in summary: *On a normal (basic HTML) web page, the # symbol can be used to link to a section within the page, so that the browser jumps down to that section after the page loads.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, basically @David K is right.

The # symbol in the URL https://developer.android.com/ is used to indicate a specific section of the page. It is called a fragment identifier.

The fragment identifier is used to identify a portion of the document that can be uniquely identified by an ID attribute or some other attribute.

In my case, it is used to identify a specific method in the CameraCaptureSession class called switchToOffline.

Reference: https://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/Fragment.html