# How to stay on Same Product after Add to Cart?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I make my E-Commerce Website using Django. When I use Add to Cart functionality on the website refresh the page & I go to the top of the page. But I want the user to stay on the same Product after Add to Cart.

Add To Cart function is made using Session in Django, not JS.

So I want when users use Add To Cart Function user stay on the same product.

I think this thing is possible using JS.

This is Add to Cart button

```py
<form action="{% url 'cart:AddCart' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
      <input hidden type="text" name="product" value="{{i.id}}">
      <button id="clickMe" class="main-btn cart cart-btn" style="padding: 5px 32px">Add <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-shopping"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909084/what-does-means-in-url) may help you

Comment: best solution is to use ajax

Comment: Can you provide a code

Comment: if you don't know how to use JavaScript and AJAX then you can send current url in `<form>` and Django may redirect` back to this url instead of displaying other page.

Answer (score 0):

user [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urlresolvers/) function

and in the function that handles the AddCart it should be something like this
in views.py

```
def addcart(request,id):
 if request.method == "POST":
    //handle the request and store it to the database
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("addcart", args=(id,)))
```

and the url.py should look something like this

```
    path("addtocat/<int:id>", views.listing, name="addcart"),
```

other way is checking if the request is POST or GET , if it's get you should render the template page normally if it's POST use the reverse function

hope that help

Comment: I think in url, you mean ```views.addcart```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use functional view to fix it by `redirect = "you're current page url name"` this one could be used in hard code way. here i have a functional view for this:

```
def add_to_cart_view(request, product_id):
    cart = Cart(request)

    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    form = AddToCartProductForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        cart.add(product)

    return redirect(f'/products/{product_id}')
```

here my detail view is `/products/<int:pk>/` and this view for adding to cart which is send request to my custom Cart class and after that process it by my class `add` method and finally I redirect it again to detail view, also I should mention that you can use `reverse` in `django.shortcuts` like this:

```
return redirect(reverse('product_detail', args=(product_id,)))
```