# Redirecting url from IE to Edge loses path after hash

Tags: redirect, internet-explorer, hash

I come with a weird behavior on Edge browser.

At my company we still need IE for some applications but now we have a new and modern web application that only works on new browsers. But old application calls the new one (mixed mess).

Problem:
When I call on IE an url like **https://myurl/path/results/#/list?jwt=encode** it opens on Edge but loses path after hash, becoming **https://myurl/path/results/#/**.
I'm using window.location.replace, but even if I simply past url on address bar when it opens on Edge it's incomplete.

If I redirect normally from IE to IE, the url stays fine.

Any idea? We are banging heads for hours.

Thanks

Edit: The new app is developed by an external entity, so I can't modify anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace the hashtag `#` with `%23` or `#!`.

Comment: No luck.
With %23, result is **https://myurl/path/results/%23/list?jwt=encode**.
With #!, result is **https://myurl/path/results/#/**.

Comment: @sensation I think the missing part after hashtag might be a common practice in modern browsers. You can take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38909084/what-does-means-in-url).