# How to pass parameter values from Postman which has '#' in it?

Tags: web-services, rest, google-chrome, postman

I am trying to call a webservice from Postman client and while doing this I am passing a value which has '#' in it. Example:

```
test = "43543#324#435"
```

But when I enter this value and click somewhere else it will remove all characters from first '#' including '#'. So the parameter will become:

```
test = "43543"
```

What should I do so that I can pass a parameter with '#' in it?

**Note: 'Postman' is a Google Chrome add-in to test Rest webservices.**

Comment: '#' has a [different meaning in url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192742/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-url-and-how-can-i-use-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

As some special characters are not allowed in URL, so we need to encode them. For this, in bulk edit mode for key-value pair, select value which contains special characters and right click. Select 'EncodeURIComponenet' and send request. It will work :)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `#` in your URL parameters.

You can find out why in this answer here: [Characters allowed in GET parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1455578/characters-allowed-in-get-parameter)

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

Not use # in URL so use encode of # is %23 and replace #.
for example show in below.

```
test = "43543%23324%23435"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 0):

open "Pre-request Script" tab , and put that:

```
pm.request.url.query.each(param => {param.value = encodeURIComponent(param.value)})
```