# Use anchor in link codeigniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, anchor

How can put an anchor to go to the **section2** of a page onchange dropdwon list  I use codeigniter ?

Dropdown

```
<select id="id_doc">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Value1</option>
<option value="2">Value2</option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$("#id_doc").change(function(){

var id_doc= $(this).val();
 window.location.href="<?php echo base_url('admin/page2'); ?>?id_doc="+id_doc;

});
```

page2

```
   <div id="section1"></div> 
   <div id="section2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally this will call the div in URL

```
<?php echo base_url('admin/page2'); ?>#section1
```

In JS follow the same thing

```
window.location.href="<?php echo base_url('admin/page2'); ?>"+id_doc;
```

or with `<a>` tag

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/page2'); ?>#section1">Go Section 01</a>
<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/page2'); ?>#section2">Go Section 02</a>
```

---

**Example**

```
https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595675/abdulla-nilam?tab=profile#top-tags
```

and this in code

```
<div id="top-tags" class="top-tags content-element">
```

Read - [What is the meaning of # in URL and how can i use that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192742/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-url-and-how-can-i-use-that)

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i don't know how to pass both the anchor section2 and the variable (id_doc). With this variable i get specific data from table to display in page2, and i want to go in section 2 of page 2. Thank you in advance.

Comment: use `<a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/page2'); ?>#section1">Go Section 01</a>` with anchor tags

Comment: To be clear I use a drop down list to select a value. With jquery I use $("#id_doc").change(function()... to get the id and pass it to the window.location.href to go to the page. That's why I can't use <a href>. I need to pass both id and anchor in window.location

Comment: You're using `var id_doc= $(this).val();` but no valu set here `<option>Value1</option>`

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11179406/jquery-get-value-of-select-onchange

Comment: sorry my mistake , I just wrote it rapidly to make you get the idea.

Comment: Happy to help :)