# JS: Play audio while new page opens

Tags: javascript, load, html5-audio

I'm trying to rebuild the audio effects this page has http://resn.co.nz/
When hovering over one of the icons an audio file is played that keeps playing even when the next page is loaded. This feels smooth and has a good UX. I have rebuild it as far as I could, however in my case when I click the icon the audio clip stops … How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when your page redirects and the new one opens, there is a break while everything is loading. On the example you cited, it is never actually redirecting the page, it is just changing the URL. You know it's not redirecting because of the # in the URL. You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192742/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-url-and-how-can-i-use-that).