# Artifactory in docker get 404 on file with a hash symbol (#) when trying to download via the UI

Tags: docker, artifactory

I had this happen on my regular instance of Artifactory oss so I made a clean install with minimum configuration change to check everything.
On a clean install of Artifactory :

- Version : Artifactory oss 7.3.2 (docker version)
- The command used to create the docker : docker run --privileged=true --name=artifactory -i -d -v /media/sdb1/Artifactory:/media/sdb1/Artifactory:z -p 8082:8082 docker.bintray.io/jfrog/artifactory-oss:latest
- Everything works fine for regular file
- I can upload a file with a hash symbol in it ex: test#1_hashtag. txt
- When I try to download it with the UI I end up here : http://my.dns.com:8082/ui/api/v1/download?repoKey=generic-local&path=test%231_hashtag.txt
- There is this error displayed :
  errors
  0
  status  404
  message "File not found."
- I can download the file with curl
- I still get the error even when I connect via IP.

I am looking to fix this since not being able to use the hash symbol (#) would need us to rename a lot of files. I don't know if it's due to redirect or something. But this installation is 100% what come out of the box.

Edit : It's not a problem of understanding how the hash symbol in the link is working, I know how it works. it's a problem of special character not being handled correctly by the app or by the redirect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of # in URL and how can I use that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8192742/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-url-and-how-can-i-use-that)

Comment: Nope, I am already aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running into a regression. This seems to have been working 6.16.2 and broken in 7.3.2 (the versions I tested, not necessarily where the regression happened, which is likely in 7.0). There is a bug open for it: https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-21460. Please vote for and follow it up for updates.

Comment: Thanks, I will mark your post as answer if the thread you linked to get solved.

Comment: Doesn't look like jfrog is going to take a look at it any soon